# Backbone save model success and error

Tags: backbone.js

I have this backbone code, create a view and model, and calls the save method to save data to database:

```
var form = document.forms[0];

var RetailerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: ' retailer.php',
    defaults: {
        name: 'company-name',
        address: 'company-address',
        phone: 'company-phone',
        icon: 'http://localhost/icon.png'
    }
});

var RetailerCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

});

var RetailerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'retailer',

    template: _.template($('#retailer-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {

        var obj = {
            name: form.name.value,
            address: form.address.value,
            phone: form.phone.value
        };

        var o = this;

        this.model.save(obj, {
            success: function(model, response) {
                console.log(model);
                console.log(response);
                o.render();
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function(model, response) {
                console.log(model);
            }
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        $('#retailer-list').append(this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())));

        return this;
    }
});

var RetailerViews = Backbone.View.extend({

});

$('#submit').click(function(e){
    var retailer_model = new RetailerModel();
    var retailer_view = new RetailerView({model: retailer_model});
    form.reset();
});
```

And the php code for receiving data is as follow:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','xxxxxx');
if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("retail", $connect);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') //POST GET PUT DELETE
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}

$name       = $data['name'];
$address    = $data['address'];
$phone      = $data['phone'];
$icon       = $data['icon'];

if(!(mysql_query("INSERT INTO retailer (name, address, phone, icon)VALUES ('".$name."', '".$address."','$phone', '".$icon."')")))
{

    echo 200;
}
else{
    echo 'record has not been insert to db';
}

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

One problem I'm having is that when the error function is called, the model returned from server still has modified attributes. I am wondering why this is happening and how can I make sure that if error happens, model stays unchanged.

Another question is in the php code, when the sql query is successful, if I echo 200, or '200', backbone will call success, but if I echo a string, backbone will call error, I'm wondering what's the logic behind it.

Answer (score 28):

From the [backbone docs:](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

> Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server before setting
>   the new attributes on the model.

If you don't want the model to update until after the save is success full pass `wait: true` as an option.

```
this.model.save(obj, {
        success: function(model, response) {
            console.log(model);
            console.log(response);
            o.render();
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function(model, response) {
            console.log(model);
        },
        wait: true // Add this
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

The Backbone

```
save( so are others like fetch, update...)
```

returns a promise. You can use

```
save().done( 
    function( data ) {}, // success
    function( err ) {}   // fail
)
```

just like how you handle promises. The `done()` method is guaranteed to execute **after the server has returned** stuff.

See the [jQuery API docs for AJAX.jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) for more information.

Comment: Isn't `.done` a synonym for `.success`? Seems like you were looking for `.always` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

Backbone returns a promise.

Here is what I have to get it works.

```
save({wait: true}).success(function(data){
   console.log(data); //returned data from server
}).error(function(error){
   console.log(error); //error returned from server
});
```